# Inconsistent situation after upgrade to 22.04 LTS from 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS from 20.04 LTS

The upgrade has not aborted and the differences with previous version are evident.

Yet, this is what I get

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (fossa-cory-tgl X59)
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

I tried a  `do-release-upgrade` again and I get

```
Calculating the changes
No candidate ver:  crda
No candidate ver:  dell-eula
No candidate ver:  dell-linux-assistant
No candidate ver:  dike6
No candidate ver:  hddtemp
No candidate ver:  hibernate
No candidate ver:  ippusbxd
No candidate ver:  ksysguard-data
No candidate ver:  ksysguardd
No candidate ver:  libpython3.9-minimal
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.10.0-1049-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.10.0-1050-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.10.0-1051-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.10.0-1052-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.10.0-1053-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.10.0-1055-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.10.0-1057-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.14.0-1024-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.14.0-1027-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.14.0-1029-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.14.0-1031-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.14.0-1032-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.14.0-1033-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.14.0-1034-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.14.0-1036-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.14.0-1038-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.14.0-1042-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.14.0-1044-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.14.0-1045-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.14.0-1046-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.14.0-1047-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.14.0-1050-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.6.0-1036-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.10.0-1049-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.10.0-1050-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.10.0-1051-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.10.0-1052-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.10.0-1053-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.10.0-1055-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.10.0-1057-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.14.0-1024-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.14.0-1027-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.14.0-1029-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.14.0-1031-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.14.0-1032-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.14.0-1033-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.14.0-1034-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.14.0-1036-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.14.0-1038-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.14.0-1042-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.14.0-1044-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.14.0-1045-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.14.0-1046-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.14.0-1047-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.14.0-1050-oem
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.6.0-1036-oem
No candidate ver:  php7.4-cgi
No candidate ver:  php7.4-cli
No candidate ver:  php7.4-common
No candidate ver:  php7.4-intl
No candidate ver:  php7.4-json
No candidate ver:  php7.4-opcache
No candidate ver:  php7.4-readline
No candidate ver:  php7.4-sqlite3
No candidate ver:  php7.4-xml
No candidate ver:  python3.9-minimal
No candidate ver:  slimbookbattery
No candidate ver:  user-manager
No candidate ver:  uswsusp

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done
```

Can someone please explain what might have happened and how to fix it ?

Comment: `(fossa-cory-tgl X59)` it is some custom build, so it is off-topic here.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. it was the Ubuntu version  preinstalled on my DELL inspiron

Comment: Then you should address this question to Dell support. Another option is to do a fresh install of vanilla 22.04.

Answer (score 3):

it was easier than I thought
I just uninstalled lsb_release

```
sudo apt remove lsb-release
sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove
```

and then installed it again

```
sudo apt install lsb-release
```

now 22.04 is correctly reported:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```